# How to use Flex and Java to download files from a server?

Tags: java, apache-flex

I'm building a Flex web application where there is an option to export data from a table to a CSV format (theoreitcally, so far, haha). Since it's a web application, I assumed the best way to go about this would be to send a request to the server to generate the file, and then either send that file (or a link to it) back to the Flex application, and use a FileReference to download the file. Is this the correct way to go about this?

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to do this, however? There are some exisitng remote objects in place that call Java functions on the server, so I thought I'd try something along those lines?

I did a bunch of research, and stumbled across things like HttpResponses and HttpServletResponses in Java, but have no idea how to bridge the gap between the client-side and server-side to use that effectively. Haha.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done is have Flex open a new tab/window and navigate it to a servlet.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url),'_blank');
```

Then use a `HttpServletResponse` to write the file out to the client, which will then be displayed in the browser. This was for a PDF, though.

In order to use an `HttpServletResponse` you'll need to write a `HttpServlet` and configure it in your `web.xml`. [Here](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/servlet/tutorial/helloworld/index.xtp) is a basic tutorial. Google has a lot more.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bunch! I only have one problem now, and that's actually loading the page, haha.

I originally tried doing that with an HTTPService object, and calling its send method, but that resulted in an error, at which point I tried using the navigateToURL method, but that just opens a blank page and nothing happens.

Comment: Does the blank page have the correct address? If so, then you have to make sure your servlet is configured and written properly. I need more information to help you properly.

Comment: The blank page has the address 'http://localhost:8400/ExportToCSV', which is correct, I do believe, based on my mapping in web.xml. Code is available at http://pastebin.com/DghDvvTc

Comment: Where does the `csvData` parameter get set? I assume in a `Filter`?

Comment: I set it, among other things, when I make a call to this function: http://pastebin.com/AbKR1Xc2. Thanks for your help thus far, by the way!

Comment: Two things: 1) Can you write "hello" to the response and see it in the browser? 2) Does your application have a name? e.g. locahost:8400/app/ExportToCSV

Comment: A HA! Once I wrote /<app-name>/ExportToCSV/, it worked perfectly! And after all that work, I found out I could just use the FileReference's save method to save data without annoying any server, oh well, now I've learned something new, haha. Thanks!!